# Convert SQL SERVER QUERY to CHART

Tags: sql, sql-server, wordpress, charts

On my wordpress webpage I would like to have a plugin/tool that allows me to make charts with an external sql server connection query.
I have been searching for plugins but I can only find those working with MySql :( or with the local wordpress DB.

Hope someone can help me, I need this for a job and I have been searching a lot.

Comment: hi @talendguy, you mean this ? https://cmsreport.com/articles/top-5-big-data-visualization-plugins-for-wordpress-13713

Comment: WP Business Intelligence --> Only uses WP local database and the other ones just attach charts. What I want is to convert a sql query into a chart from an external DB.